# Nested for loop exits early

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to compare two csv files and write to a third if they match (The comparison/writing works fine). My issue is with iteration. In the below example, my program will print 1 as many times as there are lines in s. If i move the print up a level and remove the for loop for s, it prints as many lines as there are in z. I essentially want it toi compare every row in z against every row in s but it only does it for the first row in z and exits

```
import csv
if __name__ == "__main__":

    with open("z_file.csv", "r") as f:
        with open("s_file.csv", "r") as g:
            with open("results.csv", "a+", newline="") as h:
                z = csv.reader(f)
                s = csv.reader(g)
                final = csv.writer(h)
                i = 0
                for zrow in z:
                    i += 1
                    for srow in s:
                        print(i)
```

Comment: Once you’ve looped through `s` the first time it is done. You can’t loop through an iterator twice. You’ll need to save it to a proper list.

Comment: @MarkMeyer - ooop! I guess we were typing at the same time.

Comment: @mhhollomon I would have made a proper answer, but I just have an iPad here — too hard to type.

Comment: Not an error, but you can consolidate multiple with statements on one line. `with open("z_file.csv", "r") as f, open("s_file.csv", "r") as g:` to save yourself an indent level

Answer (score 2):

The first time you hit the inner loop, all line lines are read from the file. On the second iteration of the outer loop, the reading doesn't start over, it takes up where it left off - at the end. `z` is not an array of lines, it is a lazy generator.

The easiest solution is to simply move the file open into the outer loop. So that it gets reopened in every iteration.

Faster, would be to actually read it into a list and iterate over the list.